# PHP:show datewise stock of WMS in report

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am currently working on Warehouse Management System Project:

1.Item master

2.Inward Items

3.Outward

inward outward is a bit complicated process. But that's not issue.

All is working fine,I want to generate reports.I am storing stock of each item in `item_stock` table,which gets updated as we inward(increase stock)/outward(decrease stock). I am getting current stock report fine.

But my clients requirement is he wants item stock details date-wise means what was item stock on particular date.I don't want all code, but process flow will most helpful.

I was thinking to store stock in another table of each day like cron job(not familiar) or on user login.

Answer (score 1):

This was simple.When I see this question I, think how stupid was me.
For all the beginners, who get this kind of question, here is simple solution.

1.Get Item, date from user.

2.Get current stock of that from database as date_stock.

```
"select * from item_stock where item_id=$item_id"
```

3.Get total inward quantity from that date to date_stock, subtract that from current stock.

```
 "select * from transaction where item_id=$item_id and transaction_type='inward' and transaction_date>='$datewise_date'"
```

4.Get total outward quantity from that date to date_stock, add that from current stock.

```
 "select * from transaction where item_id=$item_id and transaction_type='outward' and transaction_date>='$datewise_date'"
```

And there you go whatever date_stock was the stock for that date.